# Can't compile anything with asdf due to error in Digest::SHA module

Tags: ruby, homebrew, asdf, asdf-vm

Tried to install ruby 3.0.3 on my MacOS but got this error at start:

```
bash$ asdf install ruby 3.0.3
"$errmsg" is not exported by the Digest::SHA module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/local/bin/shasum line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/shasum line 24.
```

Compilation kept on going, but failed at a later state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to figure out what was wrong and checked /usr/local/bin/shasum command:

```
bash$ echo "test" | shasum --algorithm 256
"$errmsg" is not exported by the Digest::SHA module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/local/bin/shasum line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/shasum line 24.
```

Something was wrong with shasum. Figured out how it was installed:

```
bash$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/shasum
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  32 Dec  1 09:28 /usr/local/bin/shasum -> ../Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/shasum
```

This told me, that perl was installed through homebrew and something was wrong. So I tried to reinstall perl and it fixed the problem:

```
bash$ brew reinstall perl
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/perl/manifests/5.34.0
...
```

Now it was fine:

```
echo "test" | shasum --algorithm 256
f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2  -
```